# Divisibility of $6^{2^n}+ 8^{2^n} +12^{2^n}+14^{2^n}+16^{2^n}+18^{2^n} +24^{2^n} +28^{2^n}+42^{2^n}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Prove or disprove that for all natural $n$

$$6^{2^n}+ 8^{2^n} +12^{2^n}+14^{2^n}+16^{2^n}+18^{2^n} +24^{2^n} +28^{2^n}+42^{2^n}$$

is divisible by $259$.

I tried to apply mathematical induction, but the step is overly cumbersome.

---

*Some thoughts*. Since $2^{2^{n+1}}=(2^{2^n})^2$‚ it is fairly easy to get:

$\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
\mod & 7 & 37 \\ 
\hline
6^2     &1  &36 \\ 
6^4     &1  &1  \\ 
6^8     &1  &1 \\ 
6^{16}  &1  &1  \\
6^{32}  &1  &1 \\
6^{64}  &1  &1  \\
6^{128} &1  &1  
\end{array}$
$\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
\mod & 7 & 37 \\ 
\hline
8^2     &1  &27 \\ 
8^4     &1  &26  \\ 
8^8     &1  &10 \\ 
8^{16}  &1  &26  \\
8^{32}  &1  &10 \\
8^{64}  &1  &26 \\
8^{128} &1  &10  
\end{array}$
$\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
\mod & 7 & 37 \\ 
\hline
12^2     &4  &33 \\ 
12^4     &2  &16  \\ 
12^8     &4  &34 \\ 
12^{16}  &2  &9  \\
12^{32}  &4  &7 \\
12^{64}  &2  &12 \\
12^{128} &4  &33  
\end{array}$

$\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
\mod & 7 & 37 \\ 
\hline
14^2     &0  &11 \\ 
14^4     &0  &10  \\ 
14^8     &0  &26 \\ 
14^{16}  &0  &10  \\
14^{32}  &0  &26 \\
14^{64}  &0  &10 \\
14^{128} &0  &26  
\end{array}$
$\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
\mod & 7 & 37 \\ 
\hline
16^2     &4  &34 \\ 
16^4     &2  &9 \\ 
16^8     &4  &7 \\ 
16^{16}  &2  &12 \\
16^{32}  &4  &33 \\
16^{64}  &2  &16 \\
16^{128} &4  &34  
\end{array}$
$\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
\mod & 7 & 37 \\ 
\hline
18^2     &2  &28 \\ 
18^4     &4  &7 \\ 
18^8     &2  &12 \\ 
18^{16}  &4  &33 \\
18^{32}  &2  &16 \\
18^{64}  &4  &34 \\
18^{128} &2  &9
\end{array}$

$\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
\mod & 7 & 37 \\ 
\hline
24^2     &2  &21 \\ 
24^4     &4  &34  \\ 
24^8     &2  &9 \\ 
24^{16}  &4  &7  \\
24^{32}  &2  &12 \\
24^{64}  &4  &33 \\
24^{128} &2  &21  
\end{array}$
$\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
\mod & 7 & 37 \\ 
\hline
28^2     &0  &7 \\ 
28^4     &0  &12  \\ 
28^8     &0  &33 \\ 
28^{16}  &0  &16  \\
28^{32}  &0  &34 \\
28^{64}  &0  &9 \\
28^{128} &0  &7  
\end{array}$
$\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
\mod & 7 & 37 \\ 
\hline
42^2     &0  &25 \\ 
42^4     &0  &33  \\ 
42^8     &0  &16 \\ 
42^{16}  &0  &34  \\
42^{32}  &0  &9 \\
42^{64}  &0  &7 \\
42^{128} &0  &12  
\end{array}$

---

Some Mathematica code:

```
Format[primeFactorsFormat[n_Integer]] := 
 CenterDot @@ Superscript @@@ FactorInteger[n] //. _[x_] | _[x_, 1] :> x
tab = Table[{n, primeFactorsFormat[
     6^2^n + 8^2^n + 12^2^n + 14^2^n + 16^2^n +
      18^2^n + 24^2^n + 28^2^n + 42^2^n]}, {n, 1, 5}];
TableForm[tab, TableHeadings -> {None, {"n", "factorization"}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$6^{2^n}+ 8^{2^n} +12^{2^n}+14^{2^n}+16^{2^n}+18^{2^n} +24^{2^n} +28^{2^n}+42^{2^n}=$

$2^{2^n}(2^{2^n}+3^{2^n}+1)(2^{2^{n+1}}+3^{2^n}+7^{2^n})$

---

Now simply prove by induction:

- $\forall{n}\in\mathbb{N}:7|(2^{2^n}+3^{2^n}+1)$
- $\forall{n}\in\mathbb{N}:37|(2^{2^{n+1}}+3^{2^n}+7^{2^n})$

Comment: We answered at the same time practically.

Comment: @VividD: Mine says $14$ minutes ago, yours says $6$ minutes ago.

Comment: @VividD: BTW, I just noticed that it's your question to begin with, why have you answered it?

Comment: Why not? Also, I was not aware of your answer. I think it is a nice accident. :)

Comment: @VividD: Yep, I agree. I'd change that $1$ to $1^{2^n}$, and I'd change that $2^{2^{n+1}}$ to $4^{2^n}$, as you wrote in your answer... And finally, I'd change that "induction" to "modular arithmetic", which should be the easiest way to solve it. Of course, if I do so now then it will appear as if I've copied it from your answer... :)

Answer (score 5):

By [FLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem): $a^{2^n}\equiv a^{2^n\bmod {(p-1)}}\pmod {p}$ when $p\nmid a$. Also $259=7\cdot 37$.

The statement is false when $n=0$. I assume $n\neq 0$.

$2^n\equiv \{2,4\}\pmod {6},\: 2^n\equiv \{2,4,8,16,32,28,20\}\pmod {36}$

Now just check that $6^m+ 8^m +12^m+16^m+18^m +24^m$ is divisible by $7$ when $m\in\{2,4\}$ (simple to check)

and that $6^m+ 8^m +12^m+14^m+16^m+18^m +24^m +28^m+42^m$ is divisible by $37$ when $m\in\{2,4,8,16,32,28,20\}$ (lengthy, but all it requires are elementary modular arithmetic manipulations. I used [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=6%5Em%2B+8%5Em+%2B12%5Em%2B14%5Em%2B16%5Em%2B18%5Em+%2B24%5Em+%2B28%5Em%2B42%5Em+mod+37%2C+m%3D20) (several times, changing the value of $m$)).

Indeed all of this holds, so $259$ divides the expression $\forall n\ge 1$.

Comment: I always interpret FLT as Fermat's Last Theorem.

Answer (score 1):

$$6^{2^n}+ 8^{2^n} +12^{2^n}+14^{2^n}+16^{2^n}+18^{2^n}+24^{2^n} +28^{2^n}+42^{2^n} =$$
$$= 2^{2^n}(3^{2^n}+ 4^{2^n} +6^{2^n}+7^{2^n}+8^{2^n}+9^{2^n}+12^{2^n} +14^{2^n}+21^{2^n}) =$$
$$= 2^{2^n}((3^{2^n} +6^{2^n}+9^{2^n})+ (4^{2^n}+8^{2^n}+12^{2^n})+(7^{2^n} +14^{2^n}+21^{2^n})) =$$
$$= 2^{2^n}(1 +2^{2^n}+3^{2^n})(3^{2^n}+4^{2^n}+7^{2^n})$$

$\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
\mod & 7  \\ 
\hline
2^2     &4 \\ 
2^4     &2 \\ 
2^8     &4   
\end{array}$
$\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
\mod & 7  \\ 
\hline
3^2     &2 \\ 
3^4     &4 \\ 
3^8     &2   
\end{array}$

$\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
\mod & 37 \\ 
\hline
3^2     &9  \\ 
3^4     &7  \\ 
3^8     &12 \\ 
3^{16}  &33 \\
3^{32}  &16 \\
3^{64}  &34 \\
3^{128} &9  
\end{array}$
$\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
\mod & 37 \\ 
\hline
4^2     &16  \\ 
4^4     &34  \\ 
4^8     &9 \\ 
4^{16}  &7 \\
4^{32}  &12 \\
4^{64}  &33 \\
4^{128} &16  
\end{array}$
$\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
\mod & 37 \\ 
\hline
7^2     &12  \\ 
7^4     &33  \\ 
7^8     &16 \\ 
7^{16}  &34 \\
7^{32}  &9 \\
7^{64}  &7 \\
7^{128} &12  
\end{array}$

etc.